# css3 transition and transform none not working in ie

Tags: css

I try to stop the default transition and transform in flex-slider that works in Firefox and chrome but not in IE.

```
#carousel-2 .slides {

    margin-top: 14px;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -o-transition:none;
    transition: none !important;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) !important;
    -moz-transform: none important; 
    -ms-transform: none important; 
    -o-transform: none important;
    transform: none !important;
}
```

Comment: IE<=9 [does not support `transition`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions). I guess you're using some library and it's using JS to emulate transition on IE9, so CSS can not stop that.

Comment: @Passerby yes i think thats the problem..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the **transition** property.

Internet Explorer 9 supports an alternative, the **-ms-transform property** (2D transforms only).

btw IE10 supports both..

Thanks
AB

Comment: IE browser you are using is?